# adding GET variables to a header() location in a page template

Tags: redirect, page-template

```
header('Location: /page-name/?var1=' 
. $_GET['var1'] . '&var2=' . $_GET['var2'] );
exit();
```

The result of the above code ends up redirecting the site to:

```
http://www.domain.com/page-name/?var1=val1&amp;var2=val2`
```

I have a feeling Wordpress is cleaning the ampersand in the URL, but I don't at what point it would do that...

Edit:
With Milo's direction, I modified the redirect code to look like this and it started working properly.

```
$url = '/page-name/';
$args =  array('var1'=>$_GET['var1'], 'var2' => $_GET['var2']);
$url = add_query_arg($args, $url);
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

I'd still like to know why the ampersand got converted to HTML in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has API functions for doing both of these things- [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) and [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg).